# Tomcat 6.0 manager authentication via JDBC realm

Tags: mysql, tomcat, jdbc, realm

**I wanted to configure  Tomcat6.0  authentication via JDBC realm Configuration.****
I checked following:

-All my "users" and "roles" are stored in  MySQL database.

-MySQL JDBC drives are in tomcat\lib directory

-Tomcat-user-xml is  modified for such realm as below

> <-Realm
>   className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm" driverName="org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver"
>            connectionName="XXX" connectionPassword="YYY"
>            connectionURL="jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb"
>            digest="MD5"
>            userTable="users" userNameCol="username"
>   userCredCol="password"
>            userRoleTable="user_roles" roleNameCol="rolename"/>

After doing this  whenever I try to run Tomcat and try to run 'Manager' then it throws Authentication error on browser
and  **Catalina.log** contain following error log everytime.

> SCHWERWIEGEND: Exception opening
>   database connection
>   java.sql.SQLException: Access denied
>   for user
>   'XXX';password=XXXX'@'localhost'
>   (using password: NO)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1055)
>   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
>   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3558)
>   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3490)
>   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:919)
>   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:3996)
>   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1284)
>   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2142)
>   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:781)
>   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)  at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
>   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:352)
>   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:284)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm.open(JDBCRealm.java:703)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm.start(JDBCRealm.java:775)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1037)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:583)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
>   Source)  at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
>   Source)  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown
>   Source)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)

Please anybody have idea what is going wrong and at which point.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

use it as:

```
<Realm  className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm" 
connectionURL="jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb?user=XXX&amp;password=YYY" 
driverName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
     ...
rest same as before/>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the exception it seems that the username and/or password of the database user are incorrect. Make sure that they are spelled right and that a database user with the proper access rights is actually created.

Comment: Yes, that could be. I double check it several times, so that is not a a case I think.. thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when my server.xml was the following:

```
<Realm  className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm" debug="99"  
          driverName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"  
          connectionURL="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/authorization"  
          connectionName="root" 
          connectionPassword="xxxxx"  
          userTable="user_table" 
          userNameCol="user"      
          userCredCol="password"  
          userRoleTable="role_table" 
          roleNameCol="role" />
```

but finally I found it was wrong in tomcat7, it should be:

```
<Realm  className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm"
          driverName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"  
          connectionURL="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/authorization?user=root&amp;password=xxxxxx"   
          userTable="user_table" 
          userNameCol="user"      
          userCredCol="password"  
          userRoleTable="role_table" 
          roleNameCol="role" />
```